# Example of how to interpolate a Z value for a point using the Delaunay Triangulation in JTS

Tags: java, geometry, jts

This is a fairly remedial question. I have been looking at the documentation for the JTS DelaunayTriangulationBuilder and I am at a loss as to how to do what seems like it should be a simple thing.  I wish to take a series of points, triangulate them, and then interpolate the Z value of a random point within that mesh.  It's non-obvious from a cursory reading how to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you've loaded up the triangulation object, call `getSubdivision()` on it to get the triangulation. It uses a [quad-edge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quad-edge) data structure, which you'll need later. (It's easier to understand if you know what a half-edge or winged-edge representation is.) The resulting `QuadEdgeSubdivision` has a method `locate` that, given a coordinate, returns one of the edges of the enclosing triangle (as a quad-edge). Get its origin vertex with `orig()` and its destination vertex with `dest()`. Get another edge with `oNext()` Its destination vertex is the third vertex (also dPrev().origin() is the same vertex). Now that you have the three vertices, represent your test point as a `Vertex` and call `interpolateZValue`.

For example:

```
public static double 
interpolateZ(DelaunayTriangulationBuilder triangulation,
             Coordinate coordinate) {
    QuadEdgeSubdivision quadEdgeSubdivision = triangulation.getSubdivision();
    QuadEdge edge = quadEdgeSubdivision.locate(coordinate);
    return new Vertex(coordinate.x, coordinate.y)
            .interpolateZValue(edge.orig(), edge.dest(), edge.oNext().dest());
}
```

You're right, though. It's not obvious how to do this from reading their API.

Comment: I think you need the origin of dNext() since that says "Gets the next CCW edge around (into) the destination of this edge.".  I have added some sample code to your answer which seems to give plausible results. Does that look right?

Comment: There four "next" functions in that API. Frankly, I can't tell which one is the ordinary one. Some fiddling about to reverse-engineer the meaning of their API might be required. The code looks about right.

Comment: Fairly sure after reading the code and a tiny bit of trial and error that oNext().dest() == dPrev().orig() == the third vertex in the triangle.  Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Is it possible to pass different objects to DelaunayTriangulationBuilder than Vertex? For example, an object that extends Vertex, which would have more fields. I would like to obtain these more informative types of objects from quadEdgeSubdivision.locate(). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with JTS DelauneyTriangulationBuilder, but it sounds like you have a collection of points `(x,y,z)`, and you are submitting the 2D `(x,y)` pairs to the triangulator.  This gives you a planar triangulation of the `(x,y)` points, but also a mesh who's vertices are the original `(x,y,z)` points.

Once you have a triangulation, you wish to find the point `(p,q,r)` on the mesh that corresponds to the planar point `(p,q)`.  To do so, find the triangle `T` of the Delauney triangulation that contains `(p,q)`.  Find the [barycentric coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system_%28mathematics%29#Barycentric_coordinates_on_triangles) of `(p,q)` relative to `T`, and use these to compute a weighted average `r` of the `z` values corresponding to the vertices of `T`.  That weighted average is the `Z` value you're looking for.  In other words, `(p,q,r)` is on the mesh.

Comment: A good answer, but I am hoping JTS has a bit more specific library support for doing this for us.